# Beacon discovery using android code?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, ibeacon-android

Can anyone tell me how to use the code mentioned  [here in Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) for detecting BLE devices near my app ?The method mentioned there for getting UUID of ble device is returning only bluetooth address and not UUID.Please help...

Comment: If you mean an iBeacon style region UUID that is encoded in a manufacturer specific advertising field, rather than anything BLE standard like a service or characteristic.  There are many examples online.

Comment: I have 3 beacons near my phone.I just want to find the UUIDs of these 3 beacons using my app.Is this possible without using any 3rd party SDK libraries ??

Comment: Sure, by writing the code yourself.

Comment: Do u have any sample code ??